# Is there a way in C# that I can copy a file from one location to another and overwrite the existing file?

Tags: c#

My C# console application running on Mac OS screates a file like this:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "db1.db3");
```

Once the application has populated the file I would like to have it copied to the following two folders inside my Download directory:

```
/Users/alan/Downloads/dotnet/Japanese/Japanese.Android/Assets

/Users/alan/Downloads/dotnet/Japanese/Japanese.iOS/Resources
```

But files already exist in those locations.

How can I copy (from within the C# code) the files if they already exist?

Comment: `File.Copy(source, destination, True);` that True indicate that original file would be overwrited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
File.Copy(filePath, newPath, true);
```

The third parameter is overwrite, so if you set it to true the destination file will be overwritten.

See: [File.Copy in the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_)